# Adding an existing project to a solution edits project file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a C++ solution (`solution.sln`) where I want to include an existing library (`library.vcproj`), so I open `solution.sln` in Visual Studio and include the `library.vcproj` file for it. Then I set up the project dependencies and some include paths to get it to compile. Everything works fine.

When I'm about to commit these changes into the repository (svn) I notice the `library.vcproj` has changed. I check differences and it's just the GUID for the project that has changed. I take a look at `solution.sln` differences and find out that, as I expected, the new project GUID is in use to identify `library.vcproj`.

I've done this a *gazillion* times, and I never saw this behaviour before.

As a workaround to avoid `library.vcproj` file modification, I revert the changes to it and manually edit the `solution.sln` replacing the project's new GUID for the former one.

When opening `solution.sln` back in Visual Studio, everything works fine, but a new GUID is created replacing the libray project's in both the `solution.sln` and `library.vcproj`.

`library.vcproj` is included in several other solutions, so just committing the change would affect several other files.

What could be causing such a behavior? Is the GUID or a project reference stored anywhere else?

I'm using **Visual Studio 2005**.

Comment: +1 Interesting.  Odd.  I've never seen this happen either.

Comment: There is no question here -- file a bug report with MS?  It looks like you are not using VS 2010 -- perhaps it's fixed.

Comment: @Lou: I don't think of a bug (at the moment), since this is not the usual behaviour. I'm using Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason for this behavior. It's not a VS bug, it's actually a robust behavior!

There is another library includd into `solution.sln` with the same GUID so VS updates the GUID of the incoming `library.vcproj`.

Digging into svn logs I could find that someone copied the `library.vcproj` file from anther library and edited just the library name. Both libraries share most of the build configuration data and other stuff into the `.vcproj` file, but forgot to change the GUID value.

I'm ashamed to sa it but... that someone turned out to be me.

Thanks for your comments and time to consider the question.